# Have an offer, and a tentative start date, pending background check?

Tags: background-check

I have a written offer from HR,and as expected they are wanting a background screening. I do not have any bankruptcies,accounts in collections,charge offs repos, or foreclosures, but I have one account that several payments have been missed. If ervything else checks out on background except for those missed payments, will it cost me the offer? I know they really want me for position and my job does not involve handeling money or company finances, and I do not have any real debt whatsoever. Can someone well versed in HR please help me I'm suppose to report to work on May 27th pending this screening...

Comment: Sorry, we can't tell you what your potential employer is going to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "pending this screening"?  Is this a conditional or unconditional offer? "Pending this screening" would imply conditional, but giving you a start date would imply unconditional. If its conditional, write back and tell them you are available for work <insert current period of notice> after you get an unconditional offer.

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment yet)

Really this is dependent on the company you are applying for.

In my line of employment this may even be a police background check. It is hard to answer without knowing the role.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you'll pass the background check, i'd probably  treat this as a solid offer.

If you have reason to suspect they'll find something to object to, you might want to delay moving your household or otherwise making major investments in this until that's settled. In that case you might also want to keep channels open with any other companies that have expressed interest.

(I've never had to deal with this concern, so I don't have much to offer beyond common sense and platitudes... sorry.)